# Looping the code until user input succeed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am new to bash scripting. I wrote one code which will download the software based on the OS and software version from the user input. My code needs to loop again until the user provides right `os-bit number(64 or 32) and correct software version`. If the condition satisfied it should execute and continue the next line.

```
echo 'Enter the OS-Bit'
read osbit
echo 'Enter the Software Version To Install'
read software_version
```

**Here is my full code**

```
if [ $osbit == "64" ];then
    os_version="x86_64"
    cd $directoy_path; curl -L -O https://myblog/downloads/software-$software_version-$os_version.rpm

elif [ $osbit == "32" ];then
    os_version="i686"
    cd $directoy_path; curl -L -O https://myblog/downloads/software-$software_version-$os_version.rpm

else
    echo 'Please enter valid os bit #'
fi
rpm -vi $software_version-$os_version.rpm

echo 'Download Completed'
echo Installing $software_version
rpm --install $directoy_path/dfg-$software_version-$os_version.rpm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the conditional in an infinite loop,
and break out of it when the input is correct:

```
echo 'Enter the Software Version To Install'
read software_version

while true; do
    echo 'Enter the OS-Bit'
    read osbit

    if [ "$osbit" == "64" ];then
        os_version="x86_64"
        break
    elif [ "$osbit" == "32" ];then
        os_version="i686"
        break
    else
        echo 'Please enter valid os bit #'
    fi
done

cd "$directoy_path" && curl -L -O "https://myblog/downloads/software-$software_version-$os_version.rpm"
```

Comment: Its working. This is what I am looking for. Thank you